# Start Docker on boot on Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I am running Docker CE (Linux) on Windows server 2016. I want to run this on boot, not when I log in.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution: Use autologon. These machines are build servers, autologon is the simplest solution.

Comment: And then what? Put it into the user’s Startup folder? Use a scheduled task?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scheduled task to start `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker for Windows.exe"` at startup.

That worked and solved the problem for me.